# Hijax == sneaky Javascript redirects? Will I get banned from Google?

Tags: javascript, ajax, redirects, seo

#### Question

Will I get penalised as **"[sneaky Javascript redirects](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66355)"** by Google if I have the following Hijax setup (which requires a JavaScript redirect on the page index by google).

#### Goal

I want to implement Hijax to enable AJAX content to be accessibile to non-JavaScript users and search engine crawlers.

#### Background

1. I'm working on a static file server (GitHub Pages). No server side tricks allowed (so Google's #! "hash bang" [solution](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html) is not an option).
2. I'm trying to keep my files [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). I don't want to repeat the common OUTER template in all my files i.e. header, navigation menu, footer, etc They will live in the main `index.html`

#### Setup the Hijax

1. `index.html` page contains all OUTER html/css/js... the site's template.
2. `index.html` has a `<div id="content">` which defaults to containing the "homepage" html.
3. `index.html` has a navigation menu, with a Hijax link to an "about" page.
4. With JavaScript **disabled** (e.g. crawler) it follows link to `/about.html`.
5. With JavaScript **enabled** (e.g. most people) the link updates the url hash fragment to `/#about` and jQuery replaces the `<div id="content">` innerHTML with `$("#content").load("about.html #inner-container");`.

#### AJAX content

`about.html` *does not* contain anything extra to try an cloak content for crawlers.

`about.html` file contains enough HTML / CSS / JavaScript to display `/about.html` as a standalone page with it's own META data... e.g. `<html><head><title>About</title>...</head><body></body></html>`.

`about.html` has NO OUTER HTML template (i.e. header, navigation menu, footer, etc).

`about.html` `<body>` contains a `<div id="inner-container">` which holds the content that is injected into `index.html`.

`about.html` has a `<noscript>` tag as the first child of `<body>` which explains to non-JavaScript users that they are viewing the about page "inner content" - with a link to navigate to the `index.html` page to get the full page layout with menu.

#### The (Sneaky?) Redirect

Google indexes the `/about.html` page. However when a person with JavaScript enabled visits that page there is no OUTER html template (e.g. header, navigation menu, footer, etc). So I need to do a JavaScript redirect to get the person over the `/#about` page (deeplinking to the "about" page "state" in `index.html`).

I'm thinking of doing a "[redirect on click or after 10 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234017/jquery-redirect-on-click-or-after-10-seconds/3234034#3234034)".

The end results is that user ends up on an "enhanced" page back on `index.html` with all it's OUTER template - but the **core** "page" content is practically identical.

#### Known issue with inbound links e.g. Share / Bookmarking

It seems that if a user shares the URL `/#about` on their blog, when allocating inbound links to my site Google ignores everything after the `#` ... it allocates value to the `/` page - See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028405/hashbang-vs-hijax/5166665#5166665.

I can only try an minimise this issue offering "share" buttons on the page with the appropriate urls i.e. `/about.html`.